# ListView remove item

Tags: android, listview

How to remove item in ListView? I didn't find *remove* function.

```
ShopList = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.shopList );
ShopList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SHOP_LIST_URI, null, null, null, null);
String[] from = { DB.column_name };
int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };
shopAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, c, from, to, 
        SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER );
ShopList.setAdapter(shopAdapter);
```

Comment: AFIK, you can remove an item from listview only if you remove the item from data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to remove item in ListView? I didn't find remove function.

You don't remove an item from a `ListView`. You modify or replace the `ListAdapter` to no longer have the item. In your case, since you are using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you need to:

- Delete the item from the database (in your case, via the `ContentProvider`)
- Get a fresh `Cursor` representing the result of your query
- Call `changeCursor()` (if you are using the `Loader` framework) or `swapCursor()` to replace the `Cursor` in your `SimpleCursorAdapter` with the new one

Since you should **not** be calling `query()` on `ContentResolver` on the main application thread, you may wish to switch to a `CursorLoader`, in which case you can call `changeCursor()` in `onLoadFinished()`.

Answer (score 0):

First remove data from your database and then add

> shopAdapter.swapCursor(getContentResolver().query(SHOP_LIST_URI, null, null, null, null));